# MongoDB Cursor Timeouts while doing a lot of writes

Tags: mongodb

We have a cluster of 2 replica Sets, with 3 servers per set.  With a single collection being sharded.  We also have a quite a few more(8+) collections that we use on a daily basis. With the majority of the data being in the sharded collection with close to 100 Million records in it.

Recently we have added the requirement to obtain 100x the data that we had been getting previously, and we need to write this to mongodb.  A daemon has been set in place to perform the writes necessary to keep the database up to date.  The script performs at over 200 writes a second, with the majority going to the all separate collections.

With this quantity of writes, we have been unable to perform large reads for analytical purposes.  Receiving a combination of Cursor Timeouts client-side and server-side("Cursor Not Found").

We have attempted to do limit/skip schemes on the reads, but the problem persists. What is the best course of action to remedy this as we require both a large amount of writes, with few, but large reads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, in a case like this you want to start looking at the queries causing the time. Then you want to look at the hardware to see what's being stressed.

1. Are these queries correctly indexed?
2. How big are the indexes? Do they fit in RAM?
3. Can you provide some details on where the bottlenecks are?
4. Are you locked on on IO?
5. Are your processors running at full speed?

Also, is there anything unusual in the logs?

Basically we need to ensure that you have:
 1. Correctly built the system to handle the query
 2. Correctly provisioned the system to handle the data volumes

Comment: 1. We are only querying our reads with the _id field.

2. Our indexes are only slightly larger than the memory size, with our EC2 instances with 7.5 GB, and our indexes per replSet at 9.5 GB. We are currently in the process of upgrading to 32 GB masters.

3. I can't see any bottlenecks, just issues are fully reading the data.

4. We are generally write locked on the collection that takes the most writes, but otherwise we are fine.

5. Our processors aren't really stressed too much at all.

Comment: How do iostat and mongostat look? Are you running on EBS drives? RAIDED? How is their performance?

Comment: mongostat is showing locked % floating around 90%, with updates dominating the charts. We are currently running ephemeral on the masters and EBS on the secondaries. iostat is showing reads/s at 622 and 365 for writes/s, reads are probably high because we are currently recovering 2 32GB servers.

Comment: typically I do `iostat -dxk 1`. This has a `%util` column. If that value is high then you're taxing the IO on the disk(s).

Comment: it is indeed our disk IO is approaching max util. I guess we should RAID some EBS volumes to solve this.

Comment: Standard solutions for maxed out IO: RAID, more RAM and sharding. You'll want to start with RAID and RAM before proceeding to sharding. Also, consider using `slaveOkay` for your reads.